# Can I connect Edges to edges (to vertices)?

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

I want to keep track of who created what in my database and I was thinking about connecting my edges, with their `out` field to a `OUser` and perhaps to other relevant vertices. Is this possible or will this make walking the graph impossible?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to track who create edges or vertexes or both?

Comment: Both, if it were only vertices there would be no question for me how to do it. But connecting a Vertex by an Edge to an Edge is the thing I wonder if possible.

Comment: I don't think is possible Edge to Edge. You can set some property in Edges
like OUser link